# Spring Poller running from multiple app servers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, poller

We are using spring poller in our application to  poll the data from mySQL DB and send to a third party.
The functionality is as such working but when we moved to PRODUCTION since we have mutiple appservers , the job is running from all servers and we need this to be run in all servers to address the request coming in.

Poller time is configured to run @every 5 secs.

But even if we added the update statement, a particular record is being picked up in multiple servers since both are running at the same time.

We have the below configurations

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="datachannel"
        query="${sql}"
        data-source="dbDataSource" max-rows-per-poll="1" row-mapper="pollerdatamapper"
        update="update <table> set flag=1 where id =:Id">

        <int:poller fixed-rate="${pollerinterval}">
        <int:transactional/>
        </int:poller>

    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

PollerService class will be invoked as below for each record from the above poller

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="datachannel"
        output-channel="executerchannel" ref="pollerservice" method="getRecordFromPoller">
</int:service-activator>
```

public class PollerService
{

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PollerService.class);


public PollerDataBO getRecordFromPoller(PollerDataBO pollerDataBO)
{
  LOGGER.info("call for the Id " + Id); 
 }
```

Could you please confirm if there are any transactional setting that we can do restrict the pick of same record in other servers.

Comment: Did you try `select for update` as specified in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html?

Answer (score 0):

Right, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` should be great solution for you:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/innodb-locking-reads.html

You also ca try to play with the `isolation="SERIALIZABLE"` for the `<int:transactional/>`, but I don't have too much confidence in it.

Also I think we could improve the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` in the code like:

```
if (this.updatePerRow) {
    for (Object row : payload) {
            executeUpdateQuery(row);
    }
}
```

And skip those rows which weren't updated.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/projects/INT) on the matter.